# How to check if a folder contains n file with a certain path

Tags: java, android, file, path

I'm developing an Android app, I have to implement a function that returns an integer.

I have a folder with different files, each file is composed from a custom path like this:

- `123_part_ax0.jpg`
- `123_part_ax1.jpg`
- `123_part_ax2.jpg`
- `123_part_ax3.jpg`
- `123_part1_ax0.jpg`
- `123_part1_ax1.jpg`

I need to count all file that have the same path like: `123_part_ax` in this case `count = 4`.

*** Solution that I used ***

```
public int itemNumber(int id) {
    int nItem = 0;
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.PATH/"+id);
    File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if(listOfFiles[i].getName().contains("WHAT I WHAT SEARCH")){
            nItem++;
        }
    }
    return nItem;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is your current result? Print out `dir` to logcat to make sure you are looking in the right folder.

Comment: I presume you don't know the paths in advance, otherwise, the solution would be really simple.

Comment: Thank you all, I Solved the Problem, through my fault, I have not noticed having sent an incorrect parameter to the function, and this prevented me from having correct output. Anyway I hope that the code can help someone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such need, you can use either [`File#list(FilenameFilter filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list-java.io.FilenameFilter-) or [`File#listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FilenameFilter-) to filter the content of your folder by file name then get the `length` of the resulting array.

**For example with `list(FilenameFilter)`:**

```
int total = new File("/path/to/my/folder")
    .list((dir, name) -> name.startsWith("123_part_ax"))
    .length;
```